# What kind of animation is when real toys are played during filmed real time?

Tags: filming

What kind of animation is when real toys are played during filmed real time?

Look at this video:

It is similar to "stop motion" but I guess it is some other genre.

How is this style called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you see a person's hands moving the dolls, I don't think this can be called animation. I think the term which fits best is *puppetry*.

Comment: (Jim Henson is slowly rotating)